# Having Trouble Building a Github Project, Make Command Fails with "make: *** [doc_venv] Error 2"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hi I have a hopefully simple issue. I am trying to build https://github.com/SystemsApproach/book  It says in the readme to build the book:

> To build a web-viewable version, you first need to download the
> source:
>
> .. code:: shell
>
> mkdir ~/systemsapproach    cd ~/systemsapproach    git clone
> https://github.com/systemsapproach/book.git    cd book
>
> The build process is stored in the `Makefile` and requires Python be
> installed. The `Makefile` will create a virtualenv (`doc_venv`)
> which  installs the documentation generation toolset.
>
> To generate HTML in `_build/html`,  run `make html`.
>
> To check the formatting of the book, run `make lint`.
>
> To see the other available output formats, run `make`.

I have Python 3.8.2, GnuWin32, and virtualenv.exe in my path in Windows 10. When I try 'make html' I get;

```
virtualenv doc_venv ;\
        source ./doc_venv/bin/activate ;\
        pip install livereload ;\
        pip install -r requirements.txt
usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--read-only-app-data] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--reset-app-data] [--upgrade-embed-wheels] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--try-first-with py_exe]
                  [--creator {builtin,cpython3-win,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed] [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--no-vcs-ignore] [--system-site-packages] [--copies] [--no-download | --download]
                  [--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--pip version] [--setuptools version] [--wheel version] [--no-pip] [--no-setuptools] [--no-wheel] [--no-periodic-update] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt] [-h]
                  dest
virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: ;source ./doc_venv/bin/activate ;pip install livereload ;pip install -r requirements.txt
SystemExit: 2
make: *** [doc_venv] Error 2
```

The project isn't broken is it? Or am I broken?

Comment: Got it working in Bash shell in Windows Linux Subsystem... curious about Windows though

Comment: Not sure what you're curious about exactly: Windows and POSIX (the standard that GNU/Linux and MacOS use) are very, very different and most commands that work on one will not work on the other.  There are a few exceptions like `mkdir` and `cd` that work (in simple cases) on both.  The documentation you're following is written for a POSIX system, so those commands, and makefiles, won't work on native Windows.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist... the readme doesn't mention POSIX, how are you supposed to know?

Comment: You are right, and they should make it clear; you can file an issue on GitHub about it if you want.  You can infer it by things like, using `~` in paths which is a special character which expands to the current user's home directory in a POSIX shell, or, once you see the error messages, noting that commands are separated by semicolons which is a POSIX shell thing (Windows BAT files use `^`) and the `source` command which is a bash shell command.  But, if you don't already know these things there's no way to know.